# Cannot replace, for example, 1st with first using a regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

So what I'm trying to do here is, if I see ranking digits on the text file I want to try to convert them into their text form. For example if I see 1st ----> first. This works up to 10. I believe we have a working regex here according to [this website](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output%22). I would appreciate any assistance on this.

```
public static String firstsecondthird(String data) {
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(data);
    if (Pattern.matches("\\dst\\s", data)) {
        data = m.replaceAll("first");
    } else if (Pattern.matches(" \\dnd ", data)) {
        data = m.replaceAll(" second ");
    } else if (Pattern.matches(" \\drd ", data)) {
        data = m.replaceAll(" third ");
    } else if (Pattern.matches(" \\dth ", data)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                data = m.replaceAll(" fourth ");
            } else if (i == 2) {
                data = m.replaceAll(" fifth ");
            } else if (i == 3) {
                data = m.replaceAll(" sixth ");
            } else if (i == 4) {
                data = m.replaceAll(" seventh ");
            } else if (i == 5) {
                data = m.replaceAll(" eighth ");
            } else if (i == 6) {
                data = m.replaceAll(" ninth ");
            } else if (i == 1) {
                data = m.replaceAll(" tenth ");
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Edit:

```
//How the data is read:

import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.*;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
public class asdf 
{ 
  public static String readFileAsString(String fileName)throws Exception 
  { 
    String data = ""; 
    data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName))); 
    return data; 
  }
```

Sample input txt file:

```
1st 2nd 3rd 4th
```

Expected output:

```
first second third fourth
```

Comment: You forgot to actually give a regex in the `compile()` call. Well, technically `""` is a regex, but it's certainly not what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done like this (Java 9+):

```java
public static String firstsecondthird(String data) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\b(1(?=st)|2(?=nd)|3(?=rd)|[4-9](?=th)|10(?=th))..\\b")
                  .matcher(data)
                  .replaceAll(r -> ORDINAL_TEXT.getOrDefault(Integer.parseInt(r.group(1)), r.group(1)));
}

private static final Map<Integer, String> ORDINAL_TEXT = Map.of(
        1, "first", 2, "second", 3, "third", 4, "fourth", 5, "fifth",
        6, "sixth", 7, "seventh", 8, "eighth", 9, "ninth", 10, "tenth");
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(firstsecondthird("1st 15th 4th 7st 10th 3rd 21st"));
```

*Output*

```
first 15th fourth 7st tenth third 21st
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually matching the pattern `""` for all the replacements which is certainly not what you want to do.

According to your input, you have several replacements to make in the same input string. Therefore, you cannot use an if/else approach. Below you'll find a working example of how you could achieve what you want for numbers up to 10. The first cases are hardcoded and for replacements >3, the method `getNumberReplacement` returns the replacement string. With [`Matcher#appendReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) and the final call to `Matcher#appendTail` you can iterate over the matches and replace if desired.

```
public static String firstsecondthird(String data) {
    data = data.replace("1st", "first");
    data = data.replace("2nd", "second");
    data = data.replace("3rd", "third");

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)th");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(data);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        String replacement = getNumberReplacement(m.group(1));
        if (replacement != null) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
        }
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    return sb.toString();
}

private static String getNumberReplacement(String number) {
    switch (Integer.parseInt(number)) {
        case 4:
            return "fourth";
        case 5:
            return "fifth";
        case 6:
            return "sixth";
        case 7:
            return "seventh";
        case 8:
            return "eighth";
        case 9:
            return "ninth";
        case 10:
            return "tenth";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

*Test code:*

```
String input = "1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th 8th 10th 11th 12th 1st 7th";
String output = firstsecondthird(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

*Test output:*

```
first second third fourth fifth sixth seventh eighth tenth 11th 12th first seventh
```